# How can I show priorities on the sidebar with Jira Agile?

Tags: jira

I am trying to surface the priority field in the plan mode sidebar (issue details view?), but can't manage to add it from the manage board view. The priority field doesn't come up in the general field drop-down, but the field is available in all the screens as far as I can see. I can't find any info on the web.

Comment: The penultimate sentence is still a bit unclear, but I couldn't clean it up any further because I wasn't 100% sure what you were trying to say. Can you please clarify further what you mean by "but the field is available..." so that others can better understand your question?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can not include "Priority" in the planning mode sidebar.

There is a feature request for 6.3.0.2 that relates to this here: 
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-9741

If I were to guess, the reason you don't see it on the plan mode sidebar (that includes issue details) is because the priority is listed on the task's bar in the planning area.

This is also applicable to the version I use, 6.3.11.0.

To see fields that are eligible to be added in that area:

1. Go to Agile > Manage boards
2. Click Configure
3. Click the Issue Detail View tab
4. Add fields by selecting them from the dropdown and clicking the 'Add' button.
5. Remove fields from that view by clicking the 'Delete' button. Note that removing the fields from view will not remove the data itself.
6. Re-order the fields within their respective section as needed by clicking and dragging on the left side of the bar (to the left of the field name).

Further details can be found here: 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+the+Issue+Detail+View

Answer (score -1):

### Configuring the Jira Agile 'Issue Detail View'

[Here is the Jira Agile help page showing how to configure the 'Issue Detail View' tab.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+the+Issue+Detail+View) Please note that you need to be the Administrator of that board or have Jira Administrator global permission to be able to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately following those instructions will not not enable you to fix the OP's problem. I tried it and it doesn't work - priority does not seem to be available in that view.